Are 2-prong LED bar lights safe?
I am working on a plan to rewire my (unfinished) basement a bit to put in more lights and put them all on one switch so that the whole basement lights up when the switch is turned on. I am hoping to put all the basement lights on their own dedicated circuit out of the electrical panel.
Wife wants 11 LED bar lights in the 850 ft^2 basement. The best cost I could find on a reasonably-sized LED bar light was ten dollars apiece for a 3-foot light. See the link here - https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-3-ft-30-Watt-4000K-Bright-White-1-Light-3000-Lumens-White-Integrated-LED-Hanging-Shop-Light-Fixture-with-Power-Cord-SHOP-3X1-840-HD/305059320.
I took that as a starting point and began planning things out. When I looked at the item again on the HD website I saw that the cord from each light ends in two prongs. No ground.
I want to hardwire the lights for a slightly more robust setup (the wiring would be stapled to the ceiling, so no worries about physical damage from clumsy people or pets) and slightly better aesthetic look compared to putting outlets on the basement ceiling, plugging the lights into those outlets, and putting all those outlets on the switch. My understanding from some reading and watching is that this is a reasonably simple task. I would just have to cut off the plug and splice the wires.
Now, as far as I understand, 3-prong wiring is inherently safer than 2-prong for most electrical applications because the grounding wire and a GFCI/Ground Fault Breaker can serve as a safety measure in the case that the electricity tries to go through me instead of the wire. Now each of these lights linked above is a 30W light, so it draws about 1/4 amp in my house. (11 of them at once would draw 2.75 amps.) My understanding is that this quarter amp is enough to be fatal to me if it goes through my heart, so I am concerned about the safety of these 2-wire-no-ground cords on the lights.
So my main question is this. Are my concerns legit? Should I worry about the lack of ground in this application?

You should not hardwire the lights by cutting off the plug and splicing. That is much more dangerous than using the lights according to the manufacturers instructions. If you're worried about using ungrounded lights, just buy grounded ones instead.

The instructions for the lights provided at The Home Depot link do not mention cutting off the plug end and hardwiring. The instructions all show use of the plug as provided. Hardwiring these lights will break the ETL certification and place your insurance coverage at risk. Better to get hardwirable-from-the-factory lights.

Rather than cut off the ends hand hardwire, just install grounded outlets near the lights on your ceiling, and plug the lights in.  Won't be much additional cost to add outlets, and you'll be doing everything properly per the lights' installation requirements.

Grounding does add safety. However, plenty of things are safe enough without a ground wire. Consider, for example, typical plug-in lamps, USB power supplies (a.k.a., "phone chargers") and even some power tools. The key is proper design to minimize the possibility of certain types of problems. A device sold in the US that is UL or ETL listed has been through enough design review and product testing to determine that it is generally safe for use as supplied. Which means "if it comes with a 2-prong plug that's all you need".
However, it also means that you must use it as designed. If it comes with a cord/plug and does not come with instructions for installing hardwired then you have to install it cord/plug. Some of the lights in my basement are cord/plug connected. Some are hardwired. Sometimes they change - e.g., I have one light fixture that was originally cord/plug connected. I replaced it with an inexpensive cord/plug connected LED fixture. It failed early. I returned it to Home Depot and spent a little more a better quality hardwired fixture and removed the receptacle and hardwired it and it has been working fine for years.
On the other hand, I had another fixture that was hardwired that I replaced with a cord/plug connected fixture. Eventually I got around to wiring up a receptacle to the switch that originally controlled the light so I could stop using the pull chain (these pull chains don't last long anyway, which is another problem).
So hardwired or cord/plug/receptacle depends on the fixture. Buy the fixtures that meet your needs, not things you need to modify (and void the warranty and possibly cause other problems in the process of modifying them). I've learned from my mistakes, but you don't have to make the same mistakes.
The next thing to consider is the total amount of light. The linked fixtures are rated at 3,000 lumens each. That's close to 4 x 60W traditional incandescent light bulbs. Do you actually need the equivalent of between 40 and 44 60W incandescent light bulbs? Maybe you do, but it sounds like a lot to me. It might be worthwhile to get just one fixture to try it out. Or see if you can test one in the store - Home Depot typically has quite a few fixtures wired up and on display.
One more thing I have learned the hard way: dimmable fixtures. Not all LED fixtures are dimmable. With one pair of fixtures that I installed to replace older fixtures I knew my family would decide it was too bright so I installed them with a dimmer. But with another one I thought it would be fine...and it was ruled way too bright. So I took it out and installed a similar fixture that was dimmable and a dimmer switch. With that many lights, dimming may be important, depending on the intended use of the room. The specs for the linked light fixture say it is not dimmable, and that is very common for the least expensive fixtures.
Also consider multiple switches. 11 lights on one switch in a warehouse makes sense. In a residential basement it might not make as much sense. 2 or 3 groups, with switches next to each other for convenience, may be much more practical than having to always have them all on at the same time.

It looks like it's all plastic, there's nothing to connect ground to.
You're buying from a reputable vendor,  the product will have passed all the relevant safety regulations.

I want to hardwire the lights for a slightly more robust setup

You'll need to check to see if that's allowed, and, if so, then use an appropriate connector to connect the flexible cable to the junction box.  Some appliances bear warnings explicitly forbidding hard-wiring.
